# Nginx Unit: Static file serving with different folder name

Tags: nginx-unit

I'm rewriting a Flask application to use NGINX Unit and I am now trying to configure static resources. However I'm using flask blueprints and the folder structure is different from what NGINX Unit expects:

```
      {
        "match": {
          "uri": "/static/my-module/*"
        },
        "action": {
          "share": "/app/myapp/modules/my-module/static/"
        }
      },
```

Now what I would like is that everything after `/static/my-module/` becomes added to the local path `/app/myapp/modules/my-module/static/` like this:

`/static/my-module/main.css => /app/myapp/modules/my-module/static/main.css`

But what happens is:

`/static/my-module/main.css => /app/myapp/modules/my-module/static/static/my-module/main.css`

I don't see any way to use regex, or to set make `$uri` only be the matching part and not the full.

Given the size of the application it's not trivial to change local path. Now I could do exotic things like symlinking but that's a hassle to maintain.

I'm using unit:1.26.1-python3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible today. In the future you will be able to specify [URI rewrites](https://github.com/nginx/unit/issues/732) to reconstruct the URI to match the new layout.

For now you can mitigate the symlinking pain by using the `$uri` variable explicitly.

```json
"share": "/app/myapp/modules/my-module$uri"
```

And

```bash
$ cd /app/myapp/modules/my-module/static
$ ln -s my-module .
```

Comment: Thank you, marking this as the right answer. Thank you for linking to the right issue!

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.29 you can do this by using [inline JavaScript expressions](https://unit.nginx.org/news/2022/unit-1.29.0-released/#nginx-javascript-integration) to modify the original URI.

This configuration strips the first 17 characters from the original URI before performing the `"share"`. Note the template literal formatting to invoke the JavaScript.

```json
    {
      "match": {
        "uri": "/static/my-module/*"
      },
      "action": {
        "share": "`/app/myapp/modules/my-module/static${uri.substring(17)}`"
      }
    }
```

Comment: This requires Unit to be built with support for NGINX JavaScript, otherwise you'll get an error when submitting the config with a template literal.